# how to keep email conversation together. MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on ticketing system, where staff can send email to customers using smtp and when customer replies back i fetch it using imap and add it back to ticket.

Right now i'm adding ticketid in the subject line,so when an email comes in i can append it to existing ticket.

but at times customers remove subject line and reply which creates a new ticket.

Can anyone advice me how to get around it. I think Zendesk appends ticketid in from email address, not sure if that would work.

Comment: Just a thought! What if the "To" address is unique which has this Id. Look at the emails from github.

Comment: can you give me an example please

Comment: @coder771 so the customer receives an update on their ticket and get notified via email, the email account that sent the update isn't `NiceName@email.com`, but `10d81189-2de4-4684-acc7-1717041866b5@email.com`, where `10d81189-2de4-4684-acc7-1717041866b5` is a `guid` that you can then use as the ID for a ticket.

Comment: when my system sends an email from address would be 10d81189-2de4-4684-acc7-1717041866b5@email.com. so when customer replies back how will it be sent to our mailbox?

Comment: Configure your email server to support a catch all email box for something-*@sample.com

Comment: Just throwing out an idea... What about adding custom headers to the email itself? You could then parse the email for the custom header (which would be your ticket id) and then process it as you do now.

Comment: Replies don't generally include custom headers.  It would be better if your ticket consumer plugge dinto your SMTP receiver, not an IMAP Box, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most systems have a comment in the replies telling the customer NOT to edit the subject line.
However if they remove the subject, you can instead search the email content (if they included the previous reply with the information of the subject line) perhaps the first 200 lines if you want to limit it, using a regular expression to pattern match your subject line text string and extract the ticket number from that.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the ticket ID in all of the subject, the message-id and the body, and look for it in the subject, the References field and the body of the replies.

If you want to be extra careful and/or have many Outlook users as customers, you can even embed it in Thread-Index, which will make Outlook respond with the necessary details. Thread-Index normally has space for 160 bits of entropy, you can embed a ticket ID and still have >100 bits left over. http://rant.gulbrandsen.priv.no/aox/thread-index describes the format in enough detail.

An example:

```
To: customer@example.com
From: support@example.net
Subject: Blah blah [Ticket 34112]
Message-ID: <ticket-34112-7582349573489@example.net>
Thread-Index: 4242034112E0OYfxS/­CjgSLFGePpiQAdZqFQACzEh/­AAmOpSkA==

This relates to ticket 34112; please keep this line in your reply.

Blah.
```

If you get back a thread-index that starts with 424242 the next six digits are the issue, if you get back a References line that contains ticket-34112 you know the issue number, et cetera.